# Generic search with spring-data

Tags: spring, spring-data

I use spring data which I found very interesting but there is a problem I want a generic way to search the field of entity.

I got a entity which have many field

```
public class Lostcard implements java.io.Serializable {
    private Integer id;
    private String nom;
    private String prenom;
    private String cin;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy")
    private Date dateDeclaration;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy")
    private Date dateDuplicata;
    private String annexeAdmin;
[...]
```

So I want to do this:

```
public interface LostcardRepository extends JpaRepository<Lostcard, Integer> {

List<Lostcard> findByNom(String nom);
List<Lostcard> findByPrenom(String prenom);
List<Lostcard> findByCin(String cin);
    [...]
}
```

There is not a generic way like findByProperty(String property, Object value) ?

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way in my opinion is to use Specification. You have to make your interface extends also JpaSpecificationExecutor and then you can use your own Specification to execute query.

```
public interface LostcardRepository extends JpaRepository<Lostcard, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Lostcard> {
...
}
```

Then implement class similar to the one below:

```
public class PropertySpecifications {
    public static Specification<Lostcard> byProperty(final String propertyName, final Object propertyValue) {
      return new Specification<Lostcard>() {
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Lostcard> candidateRoot, CriteriaQuery<?>  criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
          return criteriaBuilder.equal(candidateRoot.get(propertyName), propertyValue);
        }
      };
    }
}
```

Then you can execute query:

```
lostcardRepository.findAll(Specifications.where(PropertySpecifications.byProperty("property", "value")));
```

Comment: I am getting expection for the above example. Exaception is  Parameter with that position [1] did not exist. Can anyone sort it out

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a query with parameters. You can get more complex with that, but using JpaRepository query methods you can only query for existing entity fields.

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Lostcard p WHERE p.yourfield = (:field)")
public Lostcard findByProperty(@Param("field") String property);
```

Comment: But i want to pass argument `yourfield`like you do with `field` to the `@query` string.

Comment: I don't really see the purpose of hardcoding field names into a method . The whole purpose of using query methods provided by JpaRepository is to declare specific methods without having to write any query language as it does it for you. It is far better practice to write specific methods for each property that you actually need and use them accordingly in your service implementations.